# send one parameter to wcfrestful

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest

the Following Code is My WCFRestful
unfortunately when I want to Call my Service From JavaScript the id parameter does not bind to my id parameter in Delete Function

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    void Delete(int id);

}
 public class Service : IService
{ 
public void Delete(int id)
    {
       //I do Some Work
    }
}
```

JavaScript call of my service :

```
 $(function () {
    function successDel(data) {
        alert('done');

    }
    callService("MyserviceAddress/Delete", "POST", JSON.stringify({"id":"11"}), successDel, function errordel(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }, "application/json; charset=utf-8", "json");

})
  function callService(url, type, data, successFunc, errorFunc, contentType, dataType) {
    $.ajax({
                   url: url,
                   type: type,
                   cache: false,
                   proccessData: false,
                   contentType: contentType,
                   dataType:dataType,
                   data: data,
                   success: successFunc,
                   error: errorFunc
               })
}
```

do you have any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Any helps would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Just pass the parameter in url: "MyserviceAddress/Delete/11"

Answer (score 1):

this problem  Solved by change this line

```
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
```

to

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```